# Openssl compile error

Tags: c, linux, unix, openssl, debian

I have included the following header files in a C code using openssl libraries.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#ifdef __VMS
#include <in.h>
#include <inet.h>
#else
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
```

Then I compiled the program using `gcc -o openssl -lssl -lcrypt openssl.c`
In my office this code compiled and run fine but in my house system(both are linux- debian 6 in office and Ubuntu 12.04 at home), it gave the following error:

```
/tmp/ccZcmLk4.o: In function `main':
server.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
server.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
server.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `SSLv3_method'
server.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
server.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
server.c:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file'
server.c:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
server.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file'
server.c:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
server.c:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_check_private_key'
server.c:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations'
server.c:(.text+0x165): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
server.c:(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_verify'
server.c:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth'
server.c:(.text+0x397): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
server.c:(.text+0x3c2): undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd'
server.c:(.text+0x3ce): undefined reference to `SSL_accept'
server.c:(.text+0x3e6): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
server.c:(.text+0x3fe): undefined reference to `SSL_get_current_cipher'
server.c:(.text+0x406): undefined reference to `SSL_CIPHER_get_name'
server.c:(.text+0x42e): undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate'
server.c:(.text+0x455): undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name'
server.c:(.text+0x46d): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_oneline'
server.c:(.text+0x4b1): undefined reference to `X509_get_issuer_name'
server.c:(.text+0x4c9): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_oneline'
server.c:(.text+0x50d): undefined reference to `X509_free'
server.c:(.text+0x593): undefined reference to `SSL_write'
server.c:(.text+0x5ab): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
server.c:(.text+0x5d3): undefined reference to `SSL_read'
server.c:(.text+0x5eb): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand that this is due to the absence of certain libraries in my home PC. But can anyone tell me which libraries I need to install for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Put the libraries after the source file:

```
gcc -o openssl openssl.c -lssl -lcrypto
```

See: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html

Comment: Well, that worked. But it returned a warning which i didn't get at office. `server.c: In function ‘main’:
server.c:55:7: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]`
I am afraid I will have to paste the entire code to show you where the problem is. But it was certainly not at office.

Comment: @Hari You are using different compiler versions, yes? Either adjust the flags during compilation to harmonize the warnings or get used to different compiler output. Preferably you should use the same compiler version on both locations.

Comment: I had to do `-lssl -lcrypto` (note the 'o'!) to avoid a mysterious `undefined reference to symbol PEM_read_bio_DHparams`

Answer (score 1):

put the file name before -l option