# Problem when linking mysqlcppconn-static using MySQL Connector C++

Tags: c++, cmake, mysql-connector

I am writing about a problem I had during the setup of MySQL Connector C++. I am using the binary distribution of the connector for Linux (Ubuntu 18.04), so I put the library directory outside my project (that is one of the examples given in the reference guide here (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-installation-binary.html).

In my project (Clion) I have this cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(MySQLConnectorTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

link_directories(../mysql-connector-c++/lib64)
link_directories(/opt/lampp/lib)
add_executable(MySQLConnectorTest main.cpp)
include_directories(../mysql-connector-c++/include/jdbc)
target_link_libraries(MySQLConnectorTest mysqlclient.a)
target_link_libraries(MySQLConnectorTest mysqlcppconn-static.a)
```

The mySQL istallation I have is the one provided with XAMPP. So the directory where to find `mysqlclient.a` is `/opt/lampp/lib`

The problem is when linking `mysqlcppconn-static.a`, during compilation I obtain a long list of errors like the following:

```
/home/riccardo/MySQLConnectorTest/../mysql-connector-c++/lib64/libmysqlcppconn-static.a(libmysqlclient_client.cc.o): 
nella funzione "ssl_verify_server_cert(Vio*, char const*, char const**) [clone .isra.7]":
./obj/libmysql/../../mysql-8.0.16/sql-common/client.cc:3283: riferimento non definito a "SSL_get_peer_certificate"
./obj/libmysql/../../mysql-8.0.16/sql-common/client.cc:3288: riferimento non definito a "SSL_get_verify_result"
./obj/libmysql/../../mysql-8.0.16/sql-common/client.cc:3359: riferimento non definito a "X509_free"
./obj/libmysql/../../mysql-8.0.16/sql-common/client.cc:3302: riferimento non definito a "X509_check_host"
./obj/libmysql/../../mysql-8.0.16/sql-common/client.cc:3304: riferimento non definito a "X509_check_ip_asc"
```

Can someone explain me what does this mean? Can someone suggest me how to fix?

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]: following the suggestion provided here, the compilation now goes fine. I think there is still one problem, the example program throws an exception when calling the connect method:

```
/* Create a connection */
driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
/* Connect to the MySQL test database */
con->setSchema("test");
```

I've found other posts regarding this issue, like [c++ mysql connection bad_alloc using c++ connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101671/c-mysql-connection-bad-alloc-using-c-connector?s=17aad964-56d7-4ecd-a2b0-a79e1db18cbf#new-answer)
but this doesn't help in linux, in particular i tried to follow the hint:

> I had the same error on linux.
>   The error was : I was using g++-4.8 to build the project
>   The issue lies on the version of the build tools (gcc,msvs,clang) used to build the project
>   by trying to update g++, but I have tha latest version.
>   Probably is more difficult to make this library work than writing the code I need for my application, I hope someone can suggest me what to try next.

Thanks

Comment: That means that you need to link also with a libraries, which provide missed symbols: [ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10994403/3440745) and [crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33217370/3440745).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, tried to add the following lines:
    target_link_libraries(MySQLConnectorTest ssl.so)
    target_link_libraries(MySQLConnectorTest crypto.so)
But nothing changes in the output

Comment: As it is `mysqlcppconn-static.a` library which requires missed symbols, `ssl` and `crypto` libraries should be added **after** it: `target_link_libraries(MySQLConnectorTest mysqlcppconn-static.a ssl crypto)`

Comment: Oh ok, this seems to start working but now i have this error:
/usr/bin/ld: /home/riccardo/MySQLConnectorTest/../mysql-connector-c++/lib64/libmysqlcppconn-static.a(libmysqlclient_client_plugin.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Trying to add "dl" to the end, but this makes a lot of errors for pthread.

Comment: So you need to link with `dl` library too. Just **google** for the missed symbols and you will find which library you need to link with.

Comment: Thanks for your help, compilation goes fine adding dl and pthread. Now I have errors on executing. I am following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605623/where-can-i-get-a-copy-of-the-file-libstdc-so-6-0-15

One of the simbols missing is GLIBCXX_3.4.20, but i found it in my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I solved in a simple manner. I write here what I tried and what errors I got.
I read again the develper guide and seems that using the binaries provided there could be problems because of the different compilers used for the library and for the project. I tried then to compile the sources to assure that the compiler used for the library and for my project is the same. I followed this guide: https://aaronxu17.github.io/blog/install-mysql-connector/

This didn't work, the library compiled was named mysqlcppconn8-static.a instead of mysqlcppconn-static.a, but changing the name reference to that one I have had a compilation error like this:

```
reference not defined to get_driver_instance
```

Finally I found this https://stackoverrun.com/it/q/4344116, and solved simply with

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

Now all of what tried seems stupid against the final solution. I hope this can save time to other people.
Thanks